# Suppose that A is a symmetric matrix with eigenvalues strictly between 0 and 1. Show that $(I-A)^{-1} = I+\sum_{i=1}^\infty A^i$

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

> Suppose that A is a symmetric matrix with eigenvalues strictly between 0 and 1. Show that $(I-A)^{-1} = I+\sum_{i=1}^\infty A^i$
>
> What is the error if we truncate after k terms, i.e., give a bound on $\|(I-A)^{-1} - B\|$ where B = $I+\sum_{i=1}^k A^i$?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your problem.  Can you please edit and insert the work you've done so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: For intuition you may want to compute $(I-A)(I + A + A^2 + ... + A^n)$.

Comment: This appears to be copied word-for-word from [an external source](https://algorithms2017.wordpress.com/homework/homework-3/).  [Plagiarism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially use the fact that you can extend the proof of an infinite geometric series to matrix algebra.

$(I-A)^{-1} = I+\sum_{i=1}^\infty A^I$

Notice that the right side is equivalent to an infinite geometric series where $I$ is $1$, and $A$ is $r$. Because the eigenvalues are all between $0$ and $1$, you can use $a + ar + ar^{2} + ar^{3} + ar^{4} + \cdots =\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }ar^{k}={\frac {a}{1-r}},{\text{ for }}|r|<1.$

When a = 1, this can be simplified to:

$1\,+\,r\,+\,r^{2}\,+\,r^{3}\,+\,\cdots \;=\;{\frac {1}{1-r}}$

Thus, in matrix notation, we have the right side being ${\frac {I}{I-A}}$.

Then $(I - A)^{-1} = {\frac {I}{I-A}}$

Multiple each side by $(I - A)$ and you get $I$ = $I$.

As for the lower bound, you sub in $B$ and get $I+\sum_{i=1}^\infty A^I - I + \sum_{i=1}^{k}A^i = \sum_{i=k + 1}^\infty A^i$